# How can a local object to a function survive when it is passed to an argument by reference

Tags: c++, reference

**Problem Description**

I started learning C++. But I have a problem with References. I have two classes `A` and `B`. What I am doing is that I am instantiating an object `A` in `referenceTest`. I also passed an object `B` by reference, which is instantiated in `main`. `B` has a function `addA` which initializes it's member variable `_a` and uses the local object `A` in `referenceTest` to achieve this task.

**Question**

The output `std::cout << b.a().X() << std::endl;` is printing `10`.  ​`A` is instantiated locally. So it should be destroyed after leaving `referenceTest`. I didn't understand. How come I was able to print `10`? `B` is passed by reference and it is referecing a local variable. I don't understand what I am missing in here.

---

**Source Code**

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
       A() {}
       int X() const {return _x;}
       void setX(int x){_x = x;}
     private:
       int _x;
};

class B{
    public:
    B(){}
     void addA(A & a) {
        _a = a;
     }
     A a() const {return _a;}
    private:
      A _a;
};

void referenceTest(B &b) {
    A a;
    a.setX(10);
    b.addA(a);
}

int main() {
  B b;
  referenceTest(b);
  
  std::cout << b.a().X() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It all begins and ends with what do you believe the assignment `_a = a;` does.

Comment: Is the `copy constructor` Called? And Thus we are copying the Instance a?

Comment: Where you say "B is passed by reference and it is referecing a local variable.", why do you think it is "referencing a local variable"? When you do `b.a()`, it seems that you expect this to return you the `A` instance that was created in `referenceTest`. Why? What does `a()` do? Where does it get its result from? Now, where did *that* value come from?

Comment: "Is the copy constructor called?" On the right track. Hint: in the line of code `_a = a;`, what is the `=` symbol called?

Comment: copy assignment operator.